# Why does power iteration generate almost dependent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

On the Wiki page for Krylov subspaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace it states given a matrix $A$ and vector $b$, that the vectors $b, Ab, A^2b, A^3b, ...$ "soon become almost linearly dependent due to the properties of power iteration".

What do "soon" and "almost linearly dependent" mean in this context?
What are the properties of power iteration that guarantee this behavior?

Comment: "almost linearly dependent" - a numerical way to see it would be to get the 2-norm condition number of your Krylov matrix (via SVD); you will see it blow up as you keep adding columns.